# Use SqlConnection.GetSchema to get Tables Only (No Views)

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, view, sqlconnection

When I use

```
SqlConnection.GetSchema("Tables");
```

it returns all the tables AND views for the target database.

Is there any way to just return tables? All the research I have done indicates I am doing this correctly yet it always returns the views like they are tables. I have dug down into the DataTable in debug and I can't even find a difference. The data types are reported the same... As far as I can tell, it can't differentiate between a view and a table. (It does make sense in a way since a view for all intents and purposes IS a table.)

I am using the Northwind database for testing.

I am writing the application in C#.

Here is the code that I am running to get the schema info. Pretty simple.

```
SQLCon.Open();
DataTable tables = SQLCon.GetSchema("Tables");
SQLCon.Close();
```

I would very much like to use the getschema method and not have to query the database in another fashion... if at all possible.

Comment: According to this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254969.aspx), the returned data table has a column `table_type`, which tells you whether it's a `VIEW` or a `BASE TABLE`. Use that column to filter out the views on your C# end.

Comment: I'am not using C# , but I believe GetSchema("Tables",restrictions) with your desired restrictions should work.

Comment: BeemerGuy.net, thank you that works. I was looking at the wrong damn data table. If you make your response an actual answer I can mark it as correct.

Comment: In many ways, treating tables and views as separate and distinguishable can be a mistake (indeed, some refer to views as virtual tables). If you do distinguish between them, you take away a valuable means of evolving a database - replacing one table structure with another, but writing views that mimic the original structure so that applications do not need modification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254969.aspx), the returned data table has a column `table_type`, which tells you whether it's a `VIEW` or a `BASE TABLE`.
Use that column to filter out the views on your C# end.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the complete syntax

```
DataTable table = connection.GetSchema("Tables", new string[] { null, null, null, "BASE TABLE" });
```