# Can GetSchema method work asynchronously?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, metadata, getschema

How does `GetSchema` method  of `SqlConnection` class work?
Does it run queries? Can it be called asynchronously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want the c# answer since it is in your tag see:
[Use SqlConnection.GetSchema to get Tables Only (No Views)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216564/use-sqlconnection-getschema-to-get-tables-only-no-views)

```
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

and

```
    SqlConnection.GetSchema("Tables");
```

or

```
    SQLCon.Open();
    DataTable tables = SQLCon.GetSchema("Tables");
    SQLCon.Close();
```

I would guess what this is actually doing is running a query to either the sys tables or the information_schema.tables in SQL when you open the connection.
something like:

```
   SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
```

or

```
    SELECT * FROM [database].sys.tables
```

And the equivalent calls for the other methods within the class.

For Async calls you can use

```
    Asynchronous Processing=True;
```

in your connection string

```
    string connectionString = "Data Source=yourDataSource;Initial Catalog=yourCat;Integrated Security=true;Asynchronous Processing=True;";
```

Did this answer your question?

Comment: does it mean that all methods of connection will be executed asynchronously?

Comment: I do not know the details but I would assume yes. 

You could try reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724368(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: But it DOES NOT mean that your code will generate the connections async just because of this setting, it just means it is allowed. If disallowed then it will either hold the connection until the previous one is closed or throw an error if you try to call an open connection (I havent tried it so I dont know.) 

If your code starts and ends one at a time then it is still a linear process so are you asking how to establish a thread pool for parallel processing? Or just if it allows for async?

Comment: I want to be sure that GetScheme will be executed async. If not I`ll write async await for query execution

Answer (score 4):

Can you delegate the method that calls "GetSchema"? Because SQL is transactional system, the parallel tasks we work with in c# are very different, possible even non existent in sql. The highest ranked answer on this post does a good job explaining this.

[SQL Server (TSQL) - Is it possible to EXEC statements in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571823/sql-server-tsql-is-it-possible-to-exec-statements-in-parallel)

If you cannot run the GetSchema method asynchronously, because that method just returns a data table, you could alternatively execute a query against the database that returns the same thing.

This post shows the getSchema returns a data table: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136365(v=vs.110).aspx

Read the remarks on this post: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.getschema(v=vs.110).aspx

If you call the getSchema more than once, the last call could potentially overwrite the first response.

If you are able to, you could potentially create a service queue in SQL to handle the "Asynchronous execution" but it's very complex: http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I guess it fetch data from sys tables. Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx

There is no async implementation of GetSchema.
If you need concrete details of the method try to use ILSPY.